# Lucene(.Net) geometric (lat/long) queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene, geometry, lucene.net

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC site where I plan to use Lucene.Net for searching. Some of my site content has a location attribute, and I'm thinking of incorporating location into the searching functionality.

Does functionality exist in Lucene where, if I were to define latitude and longitude fields for my documents, **the user inputs some coordinates and the system returns the closest hits to those coordinates**? If so, could you point me to some samples on how to use those features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project in contrib called [Spatial.Net](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/trunk/C%23/contrib/Spatial.Net/). Lucene in Action has a sample implementation, but looking at the test file (TestCartesian.cs) is probably just as good. Technical documentation can be found [here](http://www.nsshutdown.com/projects/lucene/whitepaper/locallucene_v2.html).